# python-django-restframwork deserializer

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I have a list like this form.

```
[{'XPos': {'$': 128.604314661},
  'YPos': {'$': 35.8662354972},
  'clCd': {'$': 1},
  'drTotCnt': {'$': 545},
  'estbDd': {'$': 19100907}
},
 {'XPos': {'$': 128.096026987},
  'YPos': {'$': 35.1753899647},
  'clCd': {'$': 1},
  'drTotCnt': {'$': 326},
},
 {'XPos': {'$': 127.050741243},
  'YPos': {'$': 37.5937747637},
  'clCd': {'$': 1},
  'drTotCnt': {'$': 412},
  'estbDd': {'$': 19711005}
},
 {'XPos': {'$': 128.582521394},
  'YPos': {'$': 35.8701796577},
  'clCd': {'$': 1},
  'drTotCnt': {'$': 427}
},
 {'XPos': {'$': 126.884639554},
  'YPos': {'$': 37.4911811753},
  'clCd': {'$': 1},
  'drTotCnt': {'$': 498},
  'estbDd': {'$': 19830831}
},
 {'XPos': {'$': 126.824997324},
  'YPos': {'$': 37.3188581763},
  'clCd': {'$': 1},
  'drTotCnt': {'$': 281},
  'estbDd': {'$': 19860101},
 }]
```

and using django-rest-framework deserializer, i want to insert that data into my database.

BUT, i have some problems.

1. I just only need **'XPos','YPos', 'estbDd'** value.
2. In converting xml to json, more nested structures have been created. (look '$')
3. Some datas do not have 'estbDd' field values.

How can i filter that datas and input to my database?

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

i referenced that site.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you can just create a new dictionary and save that to the database:

```
# assuming your list is calles 'my_list'
for item in my_list:
    if hasattr(item, 'estbDd'):
        my_model = MyModel()
        my_model.XPos = item['XPos']['$']
        my_model.YPos = item['YPos']['$']
        my_model.estbDb = item['estbDb']['$']
        my_model.save()
```

Does that solve your question?